# Using do not and don't (I do not think of it)

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs

**Man:** What do you think of the view?

**Droid:** I do not think of it.

**Man:** I don't think of it. I don't. Droids and apostrophes, I could write a book, except you are... barely a droid anymore.

(c) Deep Breath

I can't understand the difference between do not and don't in this case. I'd be grateful if somebody helps.

Comment: "don't" is how native speakers say "do not".

Native speakers don't say "do not" unless they're trying to emphasize "not".

Comment: The implication is that an android needs to be designed, built, and programmed. Its programming might focus on the fundamental, formal aspects of human language, and might omit some of the speech patterns that people use, such as idioms and contractions. Related: [Why could “Data” not use contractions?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/why-could-data-not-use-contractions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically, there is no difference. Pragmatically, the contracted form has gained in popularity to the point where the full form only appears in formal language or for emphasis ("I do *not* do that (and you saying I do is a filthy lie)"). Thus, using the uncontracted form in the casual conversation is seen by Man to be unnatural and robot-like.

Answer (score 1):

> Don’t is very frequently used in spoken English, whereas ‘do not’ is
>   used frequently in written English.

Source: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-do-not-and-vs-don%E2%80%99t/

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't think I'd go that far.  "Do not" emphasizes the word "not", and also is more formal -- almost "regal", "legalistic", or "royal" sounding.  You see "don't" written all the time.  When you see or hear the words "do not", your mind conjures up an image of a judge sitting at his bench with a gavel saying something like "Do *not* contradict me!" to a lawyer or something.