# What is the technical difference between "Don't" and "Do not" and "Aren't" and "Are not" in a question?

Tags: questions, negation

When asking a question in English, it's common to use the contraction "don't" or "aren't." At the same time, though, you can also use "do not" and "are not"

For example, you can say "Aren't you coming to the party?" and you can say "Are you not coming to the party?" However, it seems like these two sentences are not conveying the same meaning when contracted vs. not being contracted. So, is there a semantical difference between contracting or not contracting, and why is there a difference if they're the same words?

Another example may be "Don't you like peanuts?" and "Do you not like peanuts?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using do not and don't (I do not think of it)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202177/using-do-not-and-dont-i-do-not-think-of-it) // "Are you not coming to the party?" is either hifalutin' (ridiculously formal and stuffy) nowadays, or very emphatic and either irritable or astonished. // "Do you not like peanuts?" is far less stuffy, but again usually emphasising (conveying surprise). Pragmatic differences, not semantic.

Comment: Isn't it different if you say "Are you not coming to the party?" because it seems that you're answer would be "yes" if you're not going, but if you say "aren't you coming to the party?" the answer would be "no" if you're not going.

Comment: No native speaker would answer "Yes" to "Are you not coming to the party?" when they meant "No, I'm not." Logic games and English usage are often dissimilar; ELU covers the latter.

Comment: Typically, there is no semantic difference at all. However, there *can* be if the emphasis is put on the deliberate act of **negating** something. As opposed to merely rejecting the positive. *Do you **not** like* could be used to rule out ambivalence—implying an active **dislike**, as opposed to a simple *don't you like* which might include not having a preference. But that's extremely subtle, and such a distinction is almost never made. It's also entirely stylistic rather than grammatical (similar to putting *not* in bold or italics, which you can't do with a contraction).

Comment: Although, when it comes to contractions, there is at least one actually grammatical (and semantic) difference. (1) "I **can't** do it": I am unable to do it. (2) "I **can not** do it": it is possible for me to refrain from doing it.

Comment: Pointing out the obvious, the contracted form has *like* and the other has *not like*. When you open the contraction, you do not get "Do not you like?" but "Do you **not** like?" So that helps explain why "Do you not" emphasizes the negative.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the tone. 
Contractions are informal (don’t, aren’t, etc .. )

This essay in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/contractions) is quite inclusive on the subject.

Comment: I didn't - and why would anyone else - need to follow that link to accept what S Adam said.